# SimpleCursorAdapter() Depracated, how can I replace it?

Tags: android-sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to display data from SQLite to a listview. I try to use the constructor SimpCursorAdapter() but it says it's deprecated and i can't use it. Anyone any idea on how to do this without in any other way??? Below is my code:

```java
public class JournalsTab extends Fragment {
 private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         LinearLayout l2 = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.journal, container, false);

         BalanceApp myapp= (BalanceApp) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            DataSource datasource = myapp.datasource;
            datasource.open();

            Cursor cursor = datasource.fetchAllEntries();
            int[] to = {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.text4};

            dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.journal,cursor, datasource.columns, to);   //this gives error

            ListView listView = (ListView)l2.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


            return l2;   

     }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: It is a scratch line on the SimpleCursorAdapter, which means that its deprecated and I can't use it. I thought only one of these constructors was deprecated, that I could still use the other one with the Flag parameter =o, but I can't seem to do that either. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: `import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;` then use the constructor requiring the flag, and set it to `0`